# SQL Select -- Checking if value is in a comma separated list -- PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wanting to create a sql select statement that will grab rows if a given value is in a comma separated list in one of the columns of the database table.

Example Table...

**id**  |  **courses**

1   |  5, 8, 15, 19

I want to do something like this

`$course_num = 5;`

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE $course_num IS IN courses";`

1.) I don't think the "IS IN courses" part is legit.  How can I do this?

2.) For my code above, I would want to return the row because of the "5" in `courses`, not because of the "15".  So, if `$course_num = 9` no rows should be returned.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a good example of why storing multiple values in one column is difficult to deal with.

Comment: You're right, `IS IN` isn't the right syntax in MySQL, just `IN()` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in - You might find that `FIND_IN_SET()` may also work for you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set - Unless you're using MSSQL, where `IS IN` is valid syntax.

Comment: new table: id,courses, 1|5, 1|8, 1|15 etc

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() is not a good alternative,  cause it can match any occurrence in set of column data. that can get a row containing 33 when you search only 3. personally i'll looking to restruct schema of data, of using "like '%,1,%'" is more accurate

Comment: "FIND_IN_SET()" ended up being what I needed.  Thanks @Fred-ii-!  Want to add a solution so I can mark this as answered?

Comment: @gtilflm you're welcome. Barmar did find a duplicate question, so all's good, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

By adding comma in searched occurrence

```
SELECT * 
FROM courses 
WHERE concat(', ',course,',') like '%, 5,%'
```

Comment: This will never match first or last value

Comment: you're right Tristan, forgot the concat (tired..)